# how to make a search in post (in django)

Tags: python, django

I am working on making a search form in the website through which we can search for a particular blog title till now I have created a form:

```
<form action="GET" action="{% url 'posts:search' %}">
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

url for that in urls.py:

```
url(r'^results/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

function under views.py:

```
def search(request):
  query = request.GET.get('q')
  posts = Posts.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
  return render(request, 'posts/posts.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Whenever I click on search button it goes to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/GET/?q=lots+of` and gives the error `Posts matching query does not exist.`

traceback for the error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/GET/?q=lots+of

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'posts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



  Traceback:

  File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

  File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
  request)

  File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
  **callback_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\Projects\Django\devflow\posts\views.py" in 
  post_details
  17.   posts = Posts.objects.get(slug=slug)

  File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, 
  **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  403.                 self.model._meta.object_name

  Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /GET/
  Exception Value: Posts matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Can you add your Posts model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are submitting the form to the wrong URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/GET/?q=lots+of` because you have `action="GET"`.

```
<form action="GET" action="{% url 'posts:search' %}">
```

Change it to `method="GET"`:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'posts:search' %}">
```

The error message shows that your `post_details` view cannot handle the case where a post with that slug does not exist:

```
def post_details(request, slug)
    posts = Posts.objects.get(slug=slug)  # can raise DoesNotExist
    ...
```

You could use `get_object_or_404` instead:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def post_details(request, slug)
    posts = get_object_or_404(Posts, slug=slug)
    ...
```

Finally, I would recommend renaming your model from `Posts` to `Post` to match the recommended Django style, and use `post = get_object_or_404(...)` since you are fetching a single post.

Comment: thanks, @Alasdair, it was a very small mistake and yeah I will make all the changes that you have suggested (I am currently learning Django that's why I don't know much about that)

Comment: well after changing all the code now it is giving the error `Page not found` and the url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/results/?q=lots+of`

Comment: @AbhayRaghuvanshi: did you restart the server properly?

Comment: well it's working, the url for search has to be written before the url for slug,

Comment: what i was doing :
`url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.post_details, name='detail'),
 url(r'^results/$', views.search, name='search'),`

Comment: Yes, since otherwise it sees `results` as slug as well. Perhaps you better encode the first url as `post/slug` instead, to avoid overlap.